# Comparing two different data objects in Vue while reducing

Tags: vue.js, reduce

I have existing data objects and a function which is looping through by employee and doing some light math (all of this is currently working as it needs to)

The thing that I need to add into this is allow my loop to do another check as it moves through. As I'm moving through my `data_record` object, I need to check the `ID` in my `Data_record` object against the ID in the `boxes`. If they match, I need to check stock_numbers against box_numbers. If stock_numbers is greater than box_numbers then I want to put "Not Available" as a string into my computed object so that I can show that in my template instead of the data.

I have a sandbox linked below where one file is doing this code shown below, but the file main.js is trying to match up the entries so that I can then compare data on the matches, however, it is currently only returning the entries of the first one that don't have a match

How can I properly match entries between objects and compare data of those matches while still performing this current reduce function?

```
    <tr v-for="(labels, employee) in numbersByEmployee" :key="employee">
        <td>@{{ employee }}</td>
        <td v-for="date in dates" :key="date">@{{ labels[date] && labels[date].qty * labels[date].labels }}</td>
        <td>@{{ labels.total }}</td>
    </tr>



new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
data_record: [
  {
    employee: "Adam",
    ID: "Ac1874/12-15",
    Shelf_Date: "2021-07-14",
    stock_numbers: 100,
    labels: 25
  }
],

boxes: [
  {
    ID: "Ac1874/12-15",
    box_numbers: 50,
    reception_date: "2021-07-20"
  }
],

dates: ["2021-07-14", "2021-07-15"]
},
computed: {
numbersByEmployee() {
  return this.data_record.reduce((r, o) => {
    r[o.employee] ??= {};
    r[o.employee][o.Shelf_Date] ??= {
      stock_numbers: 0,
      labels: 0,
      total: 0
    };
    r[o.employee][o.Shelf_Date].stock_numbers += +o.stock_numbers;
    r[o.employee][o.Shelf_Date].labels += +o.labels;
    r[o.employee].total ??= 0;
    r[o.employee].total += +o.stock_numbers * +o.labels;
    return r;
  }, {});
}
}
});
```

Code sandbox with this portion of code, as well as a work in progress for the matching (the main.js file is where I'm just trying to match up the two objects but it's currently showing the entries that don't match)

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-glitter-83nzg?file=/src/main.js

EDIT (output for reduce function)

Currently, numbersByEmployees dumps

```
"Adam": { "2021-07-14": { "labels": 5, "stock_numbers": 40, "total": 0 }, "total": 200 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array.prototype.find to look in the box array for the id of the current item in record_data

I've forked your examaple to demonstrate this. I renamed some of the variables to match your code on stackoverflow.

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-diffie-ntmru

Let me know if I can edit this to better fit your need.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful but I'm only curious still about where I incorporate that with the current reduce function. I guess I could have your function look into the numversByEmployee function I return?

Comment: sorry, does my comment make sense?

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure what role the reduce function had? Can you show me expected output from the reduce function?

Comment: no problem. I just updated to show sample output currently. Basically, the reduce function is totaling certain data by date for each employee so that I have daily totals and grand totals. IT works exactly as it should, but I'd basically like to pull this new function into it so I have my current data, along with a status like you've shown. Basically saying "here are the aggregated numbers for this employee on this date, but it also shows if any of the products under them are available to stock with the status

Comment: I think I assumed I could just use your function to call on my existing returned result rather than the initial data set

Comment: Let me know if I can clarify that output at all

Comment: Can you show me an example where the records data have same employee twice. For example for Adam, does he always have the id: "Ac1874/12-15" id or is that only for that specific record? I'm just wondering cause you're summing up per employee but then checking the box for the id.